# Cordova oriented application POST cookie session information or pass to the default browser

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, session, cookies

We have a requirement to keep a session open between an iPhone Cordova based application and the full, default browser.  We have been able to use `window.open(_system)`, but the cookie information is lost.

Is there a way to perform this and maintain the cookie data?

Our only approach was to POST the session data, encode the data, then use a Java servlet on the receiving end, and set the cookies from the server side.  But this is convoluted and non-standard.  Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use local storage html5 api  ?

Comment: @BerlinBrown You can check out this plugin too  - https://github.com/kristianhristov/cordova-cookie-master for cookie operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our approach:
 *We didn't find a way to use cookies properly.* So 
On **the server** side ***on register***, is generated a unique token to user.

on **iPhone Cordova App** :
- on **login succes**, the server **answer a token** related with current user.
- so **every request** *from app* has user token attached to the end.

Hope this idea helped you.
Have fun ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're targeting iOS, you could try using the [Safari View Controller Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller). iOS 9 introduced this new View Controller which is faster than the InAppBrowser. Since this View Controller is the system's main browser, assets like cookies are shared with your app, so the user is still logged on in on their favorite websites.

[WWDC 2015 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/504/)